# Getting error saying for a group in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am making a game in batch just for fun.  In the game, I want to have a part in some games where you can try to persuade someone in giving you more money for a quest or to do something.  Every time I try to do this, I get a message saying                'Fail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
My code looks like this

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in          (1) do rem"') do (
set "DEL=%%a"
)
color 0a
Echo King Redwood: So 2000?
pause >nul

echo.
call :colorText 09 "1. 2500"
echo.
call :colorText 0e "2. 3000"
echo.
call :colorText 0c "3. 4000"
echo.
echo 4. 2000
echo.

set /p purs=Enter:
if %purs% == 1 goto CheckB
if %purs% == 2 goto CheckY
if %purs% == 3 Goto CheckR
if %purs% == 4 goto Convo


:CheckB
set bleu=%random:~-2,1%
if %bleu% GTR 10 (
goto CheckB )
if %bleu% LSS 0 (
goto CheckB )
set num = 2
set reward = 2500
goto Res

:Res
if %bleu% GEQ %num% goto Succeed
if NOT %bleu% GEQ %num% goto Fail

:Succeed
Echo OK 2500 will work.
pause >nul 
goto end

:Fail
echo If 2000 isn't good enough for you, I'll just have someone else do it.

:end
exit












:colorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

Basically, I only have it for the first one to set up.
I am very novice to any type of coding.  Also, the :colorText is not mine, I dont quite remember where i got it from

Answer (score 1):

When I ran it I got:

```
C:\temp\Batches>if NOT 5 GEQ goto Fail
'Fail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

As you can see there is nothing appearing between `GEQ` and `goto`. You need to use delayed expansion by changing `%num%` to `!num!`

Comment: Where are you seeing I need to add this @FloatingKiwi

Comment: Sorry, I'd modified the logic a bit in my sample. I've made an edit now. Put this on the line where you call `goto  fail`

Comment: I did that, but now it never echos the fail, even when I make num 9. Do you know anything why that would be? @FloatingKiwi?

Comment: There's an issue with your `Set` statements. These are interpreted as strings and in this case yours is `" 9"` not `9`. So either remove the white space or if you need it interpreted as a number use `Set /a Num= 9`

Comment: That has worked, thank you for the help @Floating Kiwi.